# How to make buffers writable in spacemacs?

Tags: permissions, user-permissions, spacemacs

Whenever I try to edit an existing file with spacemacs, I get "buffer is read-only". How do I give spacemacs the permission to edit any buffer on a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Press `SPC SPC`, type `read-only-mode` and select/call it. This will toggle the "read-only" status of the current buffer.

Alternatively, use shortcut `SPC b w`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following shortcut:
C-x C-q runs the command read-only-mode